# Configuring two sets of mirrored displays

Tags: display, xrandr

I'm trying to configure several Ubuntu 14.04 desktop workstations, each of which has a total of 4 monitors. I would like to configure them so that there are 2 independent screens, each of which is mirrored on two monitors.

I currently have all 4 monitors mirroring the same output with the correct resolution.

I attempted to use `xrandr` to position two of my monitors relative to the others, and use `--same-as` to do the mirroring, like so:

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --primary
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --same-as DisplayPort-0
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1-2 --right-of DisplayPort-0
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1-3 --same-as DisplayPort-1-2
```

As soon as I attempt to run the script containing these commands, two of the monitors (the ones xrandr calls DisplayPort-1-2 and DisplayPort-1-3) freeze on the image they are currently displaying and no longer update. The weird thing is if I look at the configuration graphically with arandr, the monitors are laid out exactly as I expect them to be. I'm no expect with `xrandr` though, so I could be doing something stupid here.

I'm using the radeon drivers and Xfce if that matters. I tried using the display settings menus in both Unity and Xfce before trying to use `xrandr` manually, but had even less success with those.

The output of `sudo lshw -c video` is:

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV620 GL [FirePro 2260]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:109 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f7df0000-f7dfffff ioport:dc00(size=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV620 GL [FirePro 2260]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:110 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7bf0000-f7bfffff io
```

The output of `xrandr` (after running the commands I showed above) is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DisplayPort-1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DisplayPort-1-2 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DisplayPort-1-3 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
  1920x1200 (0x44)  154.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock   74.0KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x45)  148.5MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x46)  148.5MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   56.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   50.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x47)  148.4MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.4KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   59.9Hz
  1920x1080i (0x48)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.1Hz
  1920x1080i (0x49)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   28.1KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   50.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4a)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock   27.0KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   24.0Hz
  1920x1080i (0x4b)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.7KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4c)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock   27.0KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   24.0Hz
  1600x1200 (0x4d)  162.0MHz
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock   75.0KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4e)  135.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   80.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4f)  108.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1152x864 (0x50)  108.0MHz
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x51)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x52)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   50.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x53)   74.2MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   59.9Hz
  1440x576i (0x54)   27.0MHz
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1590 total 1728 skew    0 clock   15.6KHz
        v: height  576 start  580 end  586 total  625           clock   50.1Hz
  1024x768 (0x55)   78.8MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock   60.1KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock   75.1Hz
  1024x768 (0x56)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  1440x480i (0x57)   27.0MHz
        h: width  1440 start 1478 end 1602 total 1716 skew    0 clock   15.8KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock   60.1Hz
  1440x480i (0x58)   27.0MHz
        h: width  1440 start 1478 end 1602 total 1716 skew    0 clock   15.7KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock   60.1Hz
  800x600 (0x59)   49.5MHz
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock   46.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock   75.0Hz
  800x600 (0x5a)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  720x576 (0x5b)   27.0MHz
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock   31.2KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock   50.0Hz
  720x480 (0x5c)   27.0MHz
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  720x480 (0x5d)   27.0MHz
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  640x480 (0x5e)   31.5MHz
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock   75.0Hz
  640x480 (0x5f)   25.2MHz
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0x60)   25.2MHz
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  720x400 (0x61)   28.3MHz
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! We appreciate having you here.